# RSAES OAEP certificate - public key 0 bits

Tags: rsa, x509certificate, asn.1

I have a program that create self-sign certificate of RSA algorithm.

The problem is that if I create certificate of RSAES OAEP parameters, 
when I open the certificate I see that the size of the public key is 0 bits .

Do anyone know  what is the problem?

I already checked that the ASN 1.0 Encoding of the RSA OAEP Pararmeters is ok.
And if I create certificate RSA without OAEP Parameters than the size of the public key is present ok (not as 0 bits). 
I checked in the internet and I didn’t find any certificate of RSA with OAEP pararms for example to compare with my certificate.
I will be glad for any suggestion.

- This is the certificate in PEM File:

  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  MIIFyzCCA7OgAwIBAgIDMaTyMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAMG0xETAPBgNVBAMTCFN0YW0gSXNo
  MRQwEgYDVQQHEwtQZXRhaCBUaWt2YTEPMA0GA1UECBMGSXNyYWVsMQwwCgYDVQQKEwNBUlgx
  FjAUBgNVBAsTDVByaXZhdGVTZXJ2ZXIxCzAJBgNVBAYTAklMMB4XDTAwMDEwMTEwMDAwMFoX
  DTk5MTAxMzIxNTYxNVowbTERMA8GA1UEAxMIU3RhbSBJc2gxFDASBgNVBAcTC1BldGFoIFRp
  a3ZhMQ8wDQYDVQQIEwZJc3JhZWwxDDAKBgNVBAoTA0FSWDEWMBQGA1UECxMNUHJpdmF0ZVNl
  cnZlcjELMAkGA1UEBhMCSUwwggJnMFIGCSqGSIb3DQEBBzBFoA8wDQYJYIZIAWUDBAIBBQCh
  HDAaBgkqhkiG9w0BAQgwDQYJYIZIAWUDBAIBBQCiFDASBgkqhkiG9w0BAQkEBVRDUEEAA4IC
  DwAwggIKAoICAQCizEvm86uS4/f8e7EC81OqNK+fIoCWOYJdc7iDNEbI+7l9C/zD//KiETMD
  x1V4WgBXvhokc05a0oLdJ8MlcTFUGsmrX8mxesGnY87wVeJBJ+jPQipZ+ZoA16U9d4xOQU8b
  erXUf+w6VFwoL4M3jLyL2lspHiMJPagsukxjzh1Dj/xA6tIVsSnJkffDyRC9l267pP1mXi2u
  vAT4zhSX1FLtoO3XkJ0pJarIyJeTnBLMQ5ga1gnDmUFve4tI/cLbb9fxeTF7zA+XNrTTdYrY
  9zkiMXBvnT7h0ZpGhfvobC7ULbmO/XyR3tVmuMoTu9mwNgjwCgp5f5Jt7cZbUJNbBateglcv
  +Gb9FjFjneCRU4adN87GpyAMfclq5MIO+KCoRWSDRbL/6exYMf0sE3g4ARSru/7Wm82xITNA
  fRn2qDErR421SiiuwkIlh97eiyfYeEb+n5eSOr1Qscr+tXOpEuArBDPzg0g5fo0dgomAVZvK
  hwfOS+URUmobRPuUN5ecB4dALBJkkN02qaGkCXZmzWicnheXmhTYe3og0fQpajFXUwgwguXl
  CDfy91Tn9PBYdRs0G0/gkiRABTP3sZvG3ru9I20W9tdfvN3NssBb+2AadRhSvpgP1wkHIVmZ
  /VOQN893TdmaS+WQOiocxh2LxJv7QeC8j8fi9k8LTeM4JCqJ0wIDAQABoy8wLTArBgNVHRAE
  JDAigA8xOTk4MDEwMTA4MDAwMFqBDzIwMDAwMTAxMDgwMDAyWjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQQFAAOC
  AgEAODPOHhl4J519jEExA2TIwSWLC23lloBQQPJysE0gelbyTv3xGVmJJZF+JAGvxrkvYado
  UMPc9pBF57RsB7tznhCHpcYpSRcEIEArZoxfiVkevheLsm9/gyd5RA/oD6xx8WZBFFjHW+fs
  urdJPEfR0lBHGmOKBKTa9aeqwJ5Bfi6Rm6/OvbalWBgZh2+5KYhdtMZH7JnsCCR6ZrJzLp8D
  uo5M0iIQ/J6D9pDsPBmYK3/P/c7mVhLhjUBtqelkRGO690VzoBykf9MsWE3IT58gq1Av3dGe
  J1LSgijha65s/A+l7zEC0fL7UFSXUnNCghEz+PkpcO14wFeg9UIypM0R85IOO0PBg4FVLACT
  hmBmFFJCDOCgMwO+xMQZE+eG5gOEUgESHaQfEUoU7JxPHYB/9Xxl2G69nHr2Fx0KuLrjnrym
  SgrFubQ3d+XuSTLxr/Lr7gl7EZP68uEsPcw2CXXdpsq4pvmVbrNspfHGn9SimFkEA8qmPqkt
  4wiUPCwLkvY+qZ55JnmtPWoeaekJDx7iox0TtiHlQH6Y+/Rl18zU0lITePKPbc5thPZjiwIl
  rR5O1PYzlIzE9m/7mFNitIAR2CixJRNiykgz5Q2gjYu4itmb2aHE1UuzK2mORny2gYnG7mdr
  dD2y8hDouRCuxND/kkfdDyspGSRQcnqnmpkt7nQ=
  -----END CERTIFICATE-----

Answer (score 0):

Public key is 4096 bits long in the attached certificate. Using MD5 hash with 4k keys is very strange combination as MD5 hash is too weak and all strength of 4k key is eliminated by weakness of a hash.